# How can i parse .asp files using the asp.dll?

Tags: delphi, asp-classic

I created a personal web server for my needs in `delphi`.

The problem is that can serve only static pages.
Is there any function in `delphi` where i can pass the `file.asp` as parameter and that returns me the html file?

ie.

```
Function asp2html(filenamein):String;
begin
//CODE HERE;
end;
```

I am 100% sure that this can be done i can always ask the page from IIS but then my app is like a proxy and not real webserver.

any help welcome.

Comment: Consider using a server-side environment that has not been dead for 10 years.

Comment: Assembly language is dead for 20 years.But there is no way to write a rutine in any other language to be faster than asm.
Besides  i did not ask opinions about delphi and asp i ask if anyone has a deeper knowelege .You know creating things and using things is two different things.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793112/what-web-application-framework-for-delphi-is-recommended

Comment: thanks stijn probably i am looking for something which doesnt exist.So i decide to parse on my own some commands of asp like  if then,for,response.write, so no problem.besides my server is only to serve my needs.i just wonder if it was possible and as far as i know here was the corect place for answers thansk any way :)

Comment: classic asp is so powerfull! if you know what you doing and you dont use ready frameworks like everyone does those days